# Searching in Solr for boundaries which overlap 50% of the area of the given boundary

Tags: solr, lucene, geospatial, solr4

We are given boundary data (lat,long points of a POLYGON) for all the documents indexed in Solr. I am receiving one of the boundaries as the input, and I want to retrieve all the documents whose boundary is either completely inside the given boundary or it overlaps with more than 50% of the area inside the given boundary.
In other words, boundaries with greater than 50% intersection area with the given boundary. (100% means that it is completely inside)

Boundaries are in WKT (well-known text) format such as POLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you have indexed polygonal data, and you have a query polygon.  And you want to find all indexed polygons that are at least 50% covered by the query polygon.  Makes sense.

I would start this with using a typical intersects filter (which you can see how to do in the Solr Ref Guide) and use RptWithGeometrySpatialField for the field type.  That'll get you all indexed docs (polygons) with *any* overlap.

The 50% overlap requirement is tricky though; it will be terribly slow.  You could write a Solr PostFilter that retrieves the indexed shape from the same Solr cache that underlies that spatial field and then use JTS operations to determine the overlap.  Off-hand, I think that's done by clipping and then you can compute the area.  But that will be terribly expensive to do on each search result (sorry to break it to you).  Nevertheless, maybe your requirements will allow for it if it's not a typical search app.

As a poor substitute that requires no custom coding, consider that BBoxField practically does this already, but for rectangles.  It scores based on overlap ratio, and you can filter on scores using Solr's {!frange}.